# Sorting out associative arrays according to values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

In each element of the array, the second value points to the parent of the element itself. 
So for instance in the first array, "City" is the root element and "Area" is the first child, because the second "Area" element (1) points to the key of "City.

Sample data

```
$locations = array(
    3 => array("Building", 2),
    2 => array("Area", 1),
    0 => array("Floor", 3),
    1 => array("City"),
    4 => array("Room", 0),

    13 => array("Building1", 12),
    12 => array("Area1", 11),
    14 => array("Room1", 10),
    10 => array("Floor1", 13),
    11 => array("City1")
);
```

Expected output

`Room > Floor > Building > Area > City`

`Room1 > Floor1 > Building1 > Area1 > City1`

My solution

```
$route = [];

foreach ($locations as $locationKey => $locationArray) {

    if (!isset($locationArray[1])) continue;

    $nextLocation = $locations[$locationArray[1]][0];
    $route[] = $nextLocation;
}
```

But, it wouldn't add array with no index given in array for instance, index 4 `array("room", 0);`

Also, I cannot figure out how to split the routes if one route is finished

Output I am getting:

```
Array
(
[0] => Area
[1] => City
[2] => Building
[3] => Floor
[4] => Area1
[5] => City1
[6] => Floor1
[7] => Building1
)
```

Comment: What's the output you are getting?

Comment: See updated the output of mine.

Comment: I mean what's the output you are getting according to expected output format?

Comment: You can't get output by using a for loop. You will need to recurse through the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

First save dictionary for how to get for each node and the roots:

```
$dic = [];
$roots = [];
foreach($locations as $k => $e) {
    if (count($e) == 2)
        $dic[$e[1]] = $k;
    else
        $roots[] = $k;
}
```

Then loop for all root and create path:

```
foreach($roots as $root) {
    $path = [];
    $node = $root;
    while (isset($dic[$node])) {
        $path[] = $locations[$node][0];
        $node = $dic[$node];
    }
    $path[] = $locations[$node][0];
    echo implode(",", array_reverse($path)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/Cr7D4)

Comment: Aha! I didn't think of that.